# How split a received string message (json) with specific character and insert to database in Python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python. I received a string message with JSON format like the below sample:

```
{
    "test1": "value1",
    "test2": "value2",
}
\p
{
    "test1": "value3",
    "test2": "value4",
}
\p
{
    "test1": "value5",
    "test2": "value6",
}
```

I want to split this message with the "\p" character and then insert each JSON message into the database. Like the below table.

| test1 | test2 |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 |
| value3 | value4 |
| value5 | value6 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split()` to separate each JSON object by `\p` and the newlines. Then, iterate through the resulting list to convert each string to a Python dict:

```py
import json

objects = message.split("\n\p\n")
dicts = []
for string in objects:
    string = string.replace("\n", "")
    dicts.append(json.loads(string))
```

`dicts` is now a list of dicts that you can use to add to your database.

Note that the original JSON string you posted has extra commas at the end of each object. Those need to be removed for Python to parse it correctly:

```
{
    "test1": "value1",
    "test2": "value2"
}
...
```